# Is it possible to change style of an SSH pane in iTerm2 with zsh?

Tags: terminal, zsh, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 and zsh on my mac.

I'd like to be able to easily differentiate between which panes are ssh'd and which ones are local. It'd be awesome if I could change the colors for these different cases.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you current prompt is:

```
_PROMPT=%n@%m:%c\ $\
```

Note the space character after `\`. Add some colors:

```
_PROMPT=%B%F{green}%n@%m%b:%B%F{blue}%c%b\ $\
```

[image]

Similarly, use different colors on the remote machine.